Is there a way to use graph transforms with dataloader in DGL?
I'm doing a Graph Neural Network (GNN) project with DGL library.
I’d like to apply transformations and augmentations to the batched subgraphs sampled via a DGL dataloader class.
Is there a way to do so?
In the docs they show you how to transform the full graph, not the batches like in PyTorch Geometric which has a transform parameter in its dataloaders.
